# Tether on Bitcoin Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, cryptography

USD Tether is running on the Bitcoin Blockchain right? Is it like a 2nd layer solution or how does that work?

Comment: http://www.omnilayer.org/

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen the news about Tether; http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-42065724